# loop over li's in prototypejs and get padding-left of each element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'd like to display the padding-left of each `li` element but the `hasLayout()` method does work on the elements?!! All I get in the chrome console is:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'getLayout'
```

Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/pax59/

```
<ol>
    <li>onion</li>
    <li>tomato</li>
    <li>carrott</li>
</ol>
```

```
$$('li').each(function(li) {
    var liLayout = li.getLayout();
    console.log(liLayout);
});
```

I am using prototype 1.6.1.0 and the latest version of chrome (28.0).

Comment: There is no `hasLayout` method in  prototype?

Comment: you mean getLayout()? yes there is: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/getLayout/

Comment: It is actually weird, your code is working fine with prototype 1.7.1... Are you sure the method getLayout exists in 1.6.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getLayout` method](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/getLayout) does not exist in v 1.6.1 - you probably want to update your lib or use [`getDimensions`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/1.6.1/dom/Element/getDimensions/).

Comment: thanks so much you saved my day! unfortunately i am not allowed to update the library so will switch to the api docoumentation for that old prototype version we're using :)